# Frida Java windows

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, frida

Is possible use Frida on Windows for tracing methods in Java apps?

I'm already use it for debugging APK on Android using Javascript, but I cannot do the same on Windows in a Java application.

More specific question: I need to hook some obfuscated functions and get parameters values and return value of those.

Comment: Maybe JVisualVM could be enough depending on your use case. It ships with the JDK.

Comment: VisualVM does a kind of different work. I want to debug an obfuscated java application.

Comment: please add an example

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can hook method by address + base.

https://www.frida.re/docs/examples/windows/

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "dlopen"), {
            onEnter: function(args) {
                this.lib = Memory.readUtf8String(args[0]);
                console.log("[*] dlopen called with: " + this.lib);
            },
            onLeave: function(retval) {
                if (this.lib.endsWith(moduleName)) {
                    Interceptor.attach(Module.findBaseAddress(moduleName).add(nativeFuncAddr_AKA_offset), {
                        onEnter: function(args) {
                            console.log("[*] hook invoked");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I hook JVM.dll not the java executable. It's different.

Comment: You find the symbol address, you add the base and attach with Interceptor, I'll add a snippet

Comment: I need to hook some functions for getting parameters value and return value of some obfuscated functions.

Comment: expand the main question